how to let userBot and my bot work together?
I'm trying to build telegram bot which forwards msgs from a specific channel to the bot using userBot and then the bot should react automatically to the forwarded msg
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=CHANNEL_ID))
    async def forward_to_bot(event):
      await client._forward_messages(‘bot name’, event.message)
      print(f"'{event.message.id}")
      client.start(phone)
      client.run_until_disconnected()
    
    @bot.message_handler func=lambda message: message.forward_from_chat and message.forward_from_chat.id == CHANNEL ID)
    def handle forwarded_message(message) :
      bot.reply_to(message, "Received forwarded message from the correct channel: {message, forward_from _chat.title]")
      bot.polling()

when I forward msg from the channel manually the bot works , but when the msg forwarded automatically from userBot it doesn't work , so where is the problem exactly ?
actually I found the if the user bot code is running the other bots code stopped even I didn't use it , so even if send msg to the bot itself it doesn't react to it

It's also possible the other bot is programmed to ignore messages from bots

@RoadieRich
I made the other bot

I solved the problem using multiprocessing library to let each bot (the userbot and my bot ) run in different threads
